# Exercise about conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I have to show that for sigma-algebras $\mathcal{F, G}$ with $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{G}$ and $X, Y$ real random variables with $\Bbb E[X^2] < \infty$ the following holds:

$$\Bbb{E}\bigl[(X-\Bbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}])^2\bigr] + \Bbb E\bigl[(\Bbb E[X \mid \mathcal{G}]-\Bbb E[X \mid \mathcal{F}])^2\bigr]=\Bbb E\bigl[(X-\Bbb E[X \mid \mathcal{F}])^2\bigr] \, .$$

Can you give me some hints?

Comment: What have you tried? Please add your thoughts on the problem (e.g. what about expanding the squares on both sides ...)

Comment: @saz: I don't know what to do with the terms like $\Bbb{E}\bigl[X \Bbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]\bigr]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the squares on both sides, we find that the claim is equivalent to

$$-2 \mathbb{E}(X \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})) + 2 \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})^2) - 2 \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}) \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})) = -2 \mathbb{E}(X \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})). \tag{1}$$

It follows from the very definition that $X-\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})$ and $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})$ are orthogonal, i.e.

$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X- \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})) \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}))=0,$$

or, equivalently,

$$\mathbb{E}(X \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})^2). \tag{2}$$

This shows that the first two terms on the left-hand side in $(1)$ cancel. Finally, we note that by the tower property

$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}(X \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}) &= \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbb{E} \left[ X \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}) \mid \mathcal{G} \right] \right) \\ &= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}) \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})) \end{align*}$$

where we have used in the last step that $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ (which implies that $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{G}$).

Comment: The definition of $\Bbb{E}[X\mid \mathcal{G}]$ which I have learned is that it is a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable map so that for any $A\in\mathcal{G}$ we have $\Bbb{E}[X\mathbf{1}_A] = \Bbb{E}\bigl[\Bbb{E}[X\mid \mathcal{G}]\mathbf{1}_A\bigr]$. So did you conclude by using monotone convergence or the like that $\Bbb{E}\Bigl[\bigl(X - \Bbb{E}[X\mid \mathcal{G}]\bigr)Z\Bigr] = 0$ if $Z$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable?

Comment: @user223635 No, this has nothing to do with monotone convergence. It follows from an alternative definition of the conditional expectation: $Y := \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})$ is the unique $\mathcal{G}$-measurable element such that $$\|X-Y\|_{L^2} = \inf\{\|X-Z\|_{L^2}; Z \in L^2(\mathcal{G})\}.$$

Comment: Do you perhaps know how one can show that both definitions are equivalent? I think one can do it by using monotone convergence.

Comment: @user223635 By "monotone convergence" you mean that you want to approximate $Z \in L^2(\mathcal{G})$ by elementary functions (aka step functions)...? Yes, that's one possibility to prove this.